# After Parsing Date is incremented by one Day in java

Tags: java, date

I am facing  some strange issue. I have date in string in  format "dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a" after  parsing   string   into date , it is incremented by one day.

code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String s = "09-Mar-2015 17:05:04 PM";
    System.out.println("before parsing " + s);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    Date d = sdf.parse(s);
    System.out.println("date " + d);
    String format = sdf.format(d);
    System.out.println("after  format  " + format);

}
```

o/p

```
before parsing 09-Mar-2015 17:05:04 PM 
date Tue Mar 10 05:05:04 IST 2015
 after  format  10-Mar-2015 05:05:04 AM
```

Comment: 17:05:04 is a 24 hour format. So why is there a AM/PM information in the string ? Looks for me like this date is not parseable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "a" in this line.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
```

.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String s = "09-Mar-2015 17:05:04 PM";
    System.out.println("before parsing " + s);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date d = sdf.parse(s);
    System.out.println("date " + d);
    String format = sdf.format(d);
    System.out.println("after  format  " + format);

}
```

Output

```
before parsing 09-Mar-2015 17:05:04 PM
date Mon Mar 09 17:05:04 GMT 2015
after  format  09-Mar-2015 05:05:04
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are parsing the date string without specifying a timezone. When you parse the date it is picking IST (India Standard Time) as the timezone.

So it's not just that it's the next day, but it's 12 hours later, which happens to be approximately 5am in your example.

I think if you specify the 'z' format character and include a timezone in your original string, you will not have this trouble.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z");
```

To exactly nail down the problem we need information about the timezone your machine is in.

Comment: No, this one isn't about timezones for a change.